# CurrentMotion is not change in Distance Sensor at Microsoft Band

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-10, microsoft-band

I am new is Microsoft Band app development. I am trying to detect when user is running or walking. For this I am listen **Distance** Sensor under **SensorManger**. Distance sensor are send **CurrentMotion** which has 5 state :

- Idle
- Jogging
- Running
- Unknown
- Walking

I am always get Idle state when i am walking or even running.

All other values like as : Speed, Pase, TotalDistance is update as well.

**My question is : when microsoft band is change CurrentMotion or how can i detect a user is running or not ?**

I am trying following code :

```
var paireBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
var bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(paireBands[0]);

bandClient.SensorManager.Distance.ReadingChanged += async (o, e) =>
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SensorReading.CurrentMotion.ToString());
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SensorReading.Speed.ToString());
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SensorReading.Pace.ToString());
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SensorReading.TotalDistance.ToString());
           Debug.WriteLine(e.SensorReading.DistanceToday.ToString());
        }

await bandClient.SensorManager.Distance.StartReadingsAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this. This is a bug, which will be fixed in next Band SDK release.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewGa. Can you please tell me how can I detect user running or walking ?

Comment: Until the new Band SDK package has been posted, I think the only way is to make some manual calculation like steps per second from the sensor reading. For your goals there might be other obstacles like collecting sensor events when the phone is under the lock screen or when your phone application stops being in foreground. So you might want to investigate those problems. Once the SDK is published with the fix you would switch using CurrentMotion.